# Criar tipo generico em ArrayList para persistir dados

Tags: java, genéricos, arraylist

Estou com dificuldades em entender o conceito de Dao e como eu poderia criar um tipo especifico  para armazenar os meus dados, estou utilizando a principio um ArrayList de Strings e preciso adapta-lo para um ArrayList de Objeto Produto, que teriam por exemplo código/descrição/quantidade.

Como eu declaro:

```
 private static ArrayList<String> Produto = new ArrayList<>();
```

Como eu adiciono:

```
Produto.add(codigo + " | " + descricao + " | " + quantidade);
```

Como eu leio:

```
listaDados = Produto.stream().map((string) -> string + "\n").reduce(listaDados, String::concat);
```

Como seria isto em um objeto do tipo Produto em vez de String?

Comment: Você quer saber como se ler um arraylist de objetos customizados usando stream correto?

Comment: @DiegoF preciso entender como criar um tipo genérico, no meu exemplo eu uso o `ArrayList<String>` gostaria de usar `ArrayList<Produto>`.

Comment: Não seria o caso de usar Generics Type?  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm

Comment: @NilsonUehara isto seria tipo template do c++?

Comment: Não conheço C++. Vou postar uma resposta com um exemplo de uso.

Comment: Postei uma resposta, mas realmente gostaria de entender o seu problema para poder melhorar ela. Sua dúvida está em como criar uma classe `Produto` e uma instância da mesma? Ou está em como utilizar o Generics do Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que é isso que você deseja:

```
class Produto{
    private Integer codigo;
    private String descricao;
    private Integer quantidade;

    public Produto(Integer codigo, String descricao, Integer quantidade){
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
    }

    /*Getters setters*/
    @Override
    public String toString(){
         return this.codigo+" "+this.descricao+" "+this.quantidade;
    }
}
```

Agora que você tem a sua classe `Produto`, você pode criar alguns objetos da mesma e adicionar a um `ArrayList` de `Produto`

```
Produto produtoCueca = new Produto(1, "Cueca", 5);
Produto produtoCalcinha = new Produto(2, "Calcinha", 5);

//Lista de produtos
ArrayList<Produto> listaProdutos = new ArrayList<Produto>();
listaProdutos.add(produtoCueca);
listaProdutos.add(produtoCalcinha);
```

**Explicação do `toString`:**
Em java, quando você tenta imprimir uma instância de uma classe, ele chama o método `toString` daquela classe. Mas como você não fez a definição desse método, o `toString` é chamado da classe pai, no caso `Object`, que faz com que o `System.out.println` não fique da maneira desejada.

Então se você quiser customizar como uma instância da sua classe será impressa, você tem de utilizar sobrescrever o método `toString`.

**Referência:**
[when to use toString() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329168/when-to-use-tostring-method)

Comment: Exatamente isto, vou tentar implementar a solução!

Comment: Fiz uma alteração a dois segundos atrás, porque estava utilizando aspas simples para String (muito tempo utilizando python). Então tome cuidado para não utilizar o código com aspas simples e sim duplas em `"Cueca"` e `"Calcinha"`

Comment: Agora a forma de leitura dele é diferente né ? o normal seria `Produto.get(i)` se eu der um print ele vem assim: `[estoqueDao.DaoProduto@e2d56bf, estoqueDao.DaoProduto@244038d0, estoqueDao.DaoProduto@5680a178]`

Comment: De acordo com a [documentação do java para ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) agora é se você quiser obter o objeto `Produto` que está na posição `i`, você deve utilizar `listaProdutos.get(i)`

Comment: aqui tem um exemplo minimo do problema: https://ideone.com/cXiBq2  separado em 2 arquivos main e produto e só jogar no .java e rodar

Comment: Estou sem java nessa máquina, mas qual é problema? Ao meu ver parece que o seu código está correto. Com apenas um detalhe, faz algum sentido para mim você mudar o codigo do produto para `String`, mas porque o fez com quantidade? Isso vai te causar uma dor de cabeça imensa se você quiser calcular estoque ou fazer redução da quantidade. **Quantidade eu manteria como `Integer`**

Comment: é so para testar, não vou realizar calculos por  enquanto, o problema é que na hora de realizar a leitura em vez de retornar os dados corretamente como por exemplo um array eles retornam assim: `main.Produto@15db9742
main.Produto@6d06d69c`

Comment: vou modificar o código e te explicar isso acima

Comment: era isto, eu até havia tentado  fazer: `listaProdutos.get(i).toString()` mas funcionaria da mesma forma porque seria aplicado a classe pai. valeu!

Comment: É um prazer ajudar ;)